# Vue.js is not recognizable in fastapi template (Vue.js in fastapi)

Tags: vue.js, fastapi

I want to use Vue.js with cdn in an app which served by **fastApi**.

I made a prototype w/o fast api only *cdn vue* in  **index.html** and **app.js** Both combination work well, *count* ups when button is pressed.

I move then into *fastApi* projects and uses in collaboration with its template mechanism. **app.js** seems loaded.

But It seems that vue is not loaded because both variable *message* and *count* are not recognizable( and not shown in html page) as well pressing button doesn't add *count* value.

Any suggestion what is wrong with my approach? thanks in advance.

Projects structure.

```
/static
-/js
--/myapp.js
/templates
-/index.html
my_app.py
```

content of `index.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Vue</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ count }} = {{message}}
        <h1>Hello, Vue :) </h1>
        <button @click="push_button"> ok </button>
    </div>
    <script type="module"  src="{{ url_for('static', path='/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

`myapp.js`

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                count: 100, message: "Hallo"
            }
        },
        methods: {
            push_button() {
                this.count++
            }
        }
    })
;

app.mount("#app")
```

`my_app.py`

```
app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

Comment: Instead of changing the delimiters as below, if the URL is the _only_ thing that you need expanded in your template, consider just hard coding it (or resolve it in your controller) and using `HTMLResponse` instead. Changing the delimiters will make all your Vue code look different to other developers and different from any other resource you're using with Vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the templating delimiters used by Jinja2 are the same as Vue on the frontend. You can change the interpolation delimiters on your vue app like this:

Inside `myapp.js`:

```
app.config.compilerOptions.delimiters = ['[[', ']]']
app.mount("#app")
```

And update the `index.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Vue</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        [[ count ]] = [[message]]
        <h1>Hello, Vue :) </h1>
        <button @click="push_button"> ok </button>
    </div>
    <script type="module"  src="{{ url_for('static', path='/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```